# Add Category Name to Wish List Products in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Is there a way to add category name(s) next to each product name listed in the wish list in Opencart v1.5.5.1?

I tried adding this to the wishlist.tpl but it didn't work:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

and also this code which I found on another other post and which works on the product.tpl template:

```
<?php
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id
FROM oc_product_to_category
WHERE product_id = '".$product_id."'");
$prodcategories = $query->rows;
foreach($prodcategories as $prodcategory){
$category_id = $prodcategory['category_id'];
$category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);
$caturl = (HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=product/category&path=' . $category_id); ?>
Category : <a href="<?php echo $caturl; ?>"><?php echo $category_info['name']; ?></a><br />
<?php  }  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

IN the file

```
catalog/controller/account/wishlist.php
```

Somewhere around line 108 add the product.tpl code before the code block

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                    'thumb'      => $image,
                    'name'       => $product_info['name'],
                    'model'      => $product_info['model'],
                    'stock'      => $stock,
                    'price'      => $price,     
                    'special'    => $special,
                    'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),
                    'remove'     => $this->url->link('account/wishlist', 'remove=' . $product_info['product_id'])
                );
```

The add the category name as one of the attribute of the product something like

```
                'categoryname' => $categoryinfoARRAY and then in the wishlist.tpl each product will have its associated categoryname .
```

Comment: Thank you but I still can't get it to work. I added this to wishlist.php    
`$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id
FROM oc_product_to_category
WHERE product_id = '".$product_id."'");
$prodcategories = $query->rows;
foreach($prodcategories as $prodcategory){
$category_id = $prodcategory['category_id'];
$category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);
$caturl = (HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=product/category&path=' . $category_id); 
}` and this `'categoryname' => $category_info['name'],` in the products array.